# how to read a file from folder structure in s3 bucket using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to python and trying to see how to access a file inside S3 bucket folder structure using python. Should i specify the bucket_key = "path/folder/file" to something like this? Please help

I am mainly trying to get a count on no.of rows from the csv file. But i am getting error reading the file.

```
import os
import sys
import string
import urllib
import urllib2
import boto
import boto.cloudformation
import boto.exception       
import boto.sns
import logging
from boto.s3.key import Key
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

#?pass this as a parameter?
bucket_name = "reporting"
bucket_key = "/compliance/testfile.csv"


def read_contents(bucket_key):
    # connect to the bucket
   conn = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
key = bucket_key  
# create a key to keep track 
k = Key(bucket)
k.key=key
testfile = k.get_contents_as_string()
return testfile


test = read_contents(bucket_key)
print test
```

Comment: Yes, an S3 key is the full path to the file.

Comment: I tried bucket-name/foldername/fileInFolder. But havent had luck with it. Getting error in accessing the file.

Comment: Show your code. What version of Boto/AWS SDK are you using?

Comment: I have the code in the post now.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 404 Not Found
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.

Comment: Try it without the preceding slash, like: `bucket_key = "compliance/testfile.csv"`

Comment: it worked with removing the slash. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

### High level access to S3 using safe operations

Hi, let's define some fonctions to access and download a file from AWS S3.
First of all, you have to connect to Amazon.

#### Connect to S3

```
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

def s3_conn(conf):
  """ Connect to S3 
  :param conf - dict: contains AWS credentials
  :return S3Connection:
  """
  try:
    s3 = boto.connect_s3()
    return s3
  except:
    key_id = conf.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    access_key = conf.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    return S3Connection(key_id, access_key)
```

The `conf` object refers to a dictionary containing your AWS credentials.
Once you did this, we can focus on the download step.

#### Download a file from S3

```
import os
from boto.s3.key import Key

def download_file_s3(filename, dirs3, output_path, buckets3, conf):
  """
  :param filename - str: filename
  :param dirs3 - str: full path to file
  :param output_path - str: output path
  :param buckets3 - str: bucket name
  :param conf - dict: contains AWS credentials
  """

  print('Downloading file from s3, filename={}, output_path={}, dirs3={}, buckets3={}'.format(
    filename, output_path, dirs3, buckets3))
  filepath = '/'.join([dirs3, filename])
  s3 = s3_conn(conf)
  bucket = s3.get_bucket(buckets3)
  key = bucket.get_key(filepath)
  key.get_contents_to_filename(os.path.join(output_path, filename))
  print('File saved, output path={}'.format(os.path.join(output_path, filename)))
  key.close()
  s3.close()
```

`download_file_s3` takes as argument the `filename`, `dirs3` corresponds to the full path to your file, you can also set the `output_path`, the name of the `buckets3` and finally, you have to give the dictionary containing your AWS credentials.
So, this function determines your filepath, connects to Amazon S3, get the wanted bucket, and it downloads your file.

#### Safe download (error handling)

If you want to safely download a file from S3, just use this function :

```
from boto.exception import S3ResponseError

def safe_download_from_s3(filename, output_path, buckets3, dirs3, conf):
  """
  :param filename - str: filename
  :param dirs3 - str: full path to file
  :param output_path - str: output path
  :param buckets3 - str: bucket name
  :param conf - dict: contains AWS credentials
  """

  print('Trying to download file from s3, filename={}, output_path={}, dirs3={}, buckets3={}'.format(
    filename, output_path, dirs3, buckets3))
  try:
      download_file_s3(filename, dirs3, output_path, buckets3, conf)
      print('File downloaded successfully')
  except S3ResponseError as err:
      print('An S3ResponseError occurred while downloading, err={}'.format(err))
  except TypeError as err:
      print('A TypeError occurred while downloading, err={}'.format(err))
  except NameError as err:
      print('A NameError occurred while downloading, err={}'.format(err))
  except:
      print('Unexpected error, exec_info={}'.format(sys.exc_info()[0]))
```

In this example, `conf` is a dictionary like this :

```
conf = {'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID':'<your_aws_access_key_id>',
        'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY':'<your_aws_secret_access>'}
```

but you could also and export your credentials into environment variables :

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<your_aws_access_key_id>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<your_aws_secret_access>
```

And just do :

```
import os
conf=os.environ
```

That is what I recommend to you.

I hope this helps. If you have questions, you're welcome.